# Count not working on select with alias

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a scope called **add_has_relation** 
that does a left join with another table and renames with AS a field like this:

```
scope :add_has_relation, lambda { |fan|
  joins("LEFT JOIN fan_influencers fi ON fi.influencer_id = influencers.id
    AND fi.fan_id = #{fan.id}").select('influencers.*', 'fi.id AS has_relation') if fan.present?
}
```

If I use it, everything works great and I can use that field new field:

> Influencer.add_has_relation(Fan.find(2)).first.has_relation

But if I use COUNT like this:

> Influencer.add_has_relation(Fan.find(2)).count

It fails with **StatementInvalid** because for some reason it is running this query:

> SELECT COUNT(influencers.*, fi.id AS has_relation) FROM "inf...

and so I have to use it like this:

> Influencer.add_has_relation(Fan.find(2)).map(&:id).count

But I don't think it is neat. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use field parameters in the `count` method: 
`Influencer.add_has_relation(Fan.find(2)).count(:id)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it this way?

```
SELECT COUNT(influencers.*, fi.id) AS has_relation FROM "inf...
```

Comment: I did not do the sql query. I just copied what rails executed when using the scopes like shown above.

Comment: When you're using count function, you are supposed to use alias outside, not inside.  I suppose that is the reason you're getting this error.

Comment: Yes I know, but this is the way ActiveRecord or whatever executes this line:

Comment: Influencer.add_has_relation(Fan.find(2)).count